XRPL get access to accounts from Seed?
xrpl.wallet.Wallet.from_seed(seed)
Learning how xrpl works in Python. The above returns the wallet including the public and private key. What is to prevent someone from brute force guessing this seed string? The seed is only 31 characters long.
I am struggling to understand how safe this is, can someone explain? Theoretically, couldn't someone write a script to randomly guess seed strings and over time eventually get access to someone's wallet via their public and private keys? Let's say they had a thousand containers spun up brute force testing random seeds, eventually wouldn't one gain access to a wallet?
Thanks!
